# Can yeast leaven cornmeal?

Tags: yeast, leavening, cornmeal

Can yeast leaven cornmeal? If not, why? The [lack of gluten](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/104816/does-leavened-bread-made-with-yeast-require-gluten-to-rise)?

Answer (score -1):

Most bread recipes that have cornmeal usually use a combination of cornmeal and wheat flour.  I have made pizza crusts with cornmeal leavened with yeast, but they are about 1/3 to 1/2 cornmeal.  Any more than that and they have a texture more like polenta or grits than bread.  Short answer, yes, if you mix the cornmeal with wheat flour.

Comment: "_Most bread recipes that have cornmeal usually use a combination of cornmeal and wheat flour._" Yes.